# call Yii::$app frontend from backend yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i install this plugin for change theme in frontend https://github.com/Singrana/thememanager
install like manual.

in my frontend/config/main.php

```
'components' => [
'view'=>
        [

        'theme' =>
            [
                'class'     =>  'singrana\thememanager\components\ThemeManager',
                'current'   =>  'siteeee',

                'themes'    =>
                [
                    'site'  =>
                    [
                        'pathMap'   =>
                        [
                            '@app/views'            =>  '@frontend/themes/site',
                            '@app/views/layouts'    =>  '@frontend/themes/site/layouts',
                        ],
                        //'defaultLayout'             =>  '//inner',
                    ],

                    'siteeee'  =>
                    [
                        'pathMap'   =>
                        [
                            '@app/views'            =>  '@frontend/themes/siteeee',
                            '@app/views/layouts'    =>  '@frontend/themes/siteeee/layouts',
                        ],
                        //'defaultLayout'             =>  '//inner',
                    ],

                ],
        ],
    ],

],
```

but i need to call `\Yii::$app->view->theme->changeTheme('themeName');`, like in manual, to change theme , how can i do this in backend side ?

Comment: Why don't you copy frontend configuration to backend config?

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli because I need to change the theme only in frontend side , in backend side i have theme and dont want change.

Comment: Why do you need to change, runtime, theme from backend to frontend? Maybe you need to store this change in database, so when frontend starts it loads the right theme.

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli ok but plugin have functional to add new themes and i want to use this in my backend side.

Comment: Yes, plugin has functionals to add new themes, but in the context in which you use it